# capitals or not for "open source"?

Tags: capitalization

Quite a simple question (I hope).

Which is the correct way to write this within a sentence*:

1. Open Source
2. Open-Source
3. Open source
4. Open-source
5. open source
6. open-source
7. some other way?

(*By within a sentence, I mean there is at least one word before the usage meaning that no beginning-of-sentence capital is required)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source_(disambiguation)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unlike a lot of English, it turns out there is in fact a definitive source to start looking to for an answer to this. The term was invented and [trademarked](http://opensource.org/trademark-guidelines) by the [Open Source Initiative (OSI)](http://opensource.org/), and they claim to maintain [the definition](http://opensource.org/osd) for exactly what it means.

So how do they do it on their own materials? Well, from poking around their website, I see two common methods:

1. open source. "Open" is capitalized only if it starts a sentence.
2. open-source. (Same comment).

The only time you see Open Source is when its part of the title of their organization name (iow: followed by "Initiative").

That being said, occasionally in the wild you will see open-source software abbreviated as "OSS".  I also often see both words capitalized. Personally I tell myself that is because in those circumstances they are talking about it as a whole, thus personifying it, thus it gets its words capitalized just like a proper name would. That's probably just a rationalization though. Still, a run through [Slashdot shows me](http://science.slashdot.org/story/14/02/05/1751234/former-red-hat-coo-helps-health-care-providers-work-together-video) that when used as an adjective term, it is pretty much always lower case.

So if I were to come up with rules based on the authority of the OSI and common use among practitioners it would be the following:

1. open source or open-source when used as an adjective. (The hyphenless version is more common)
2. Open Source when used alone as a noun (or occasionally a verb).
3. OSS when abbreviated (to mean "open source software").

Answer (score -1):

Capitals are used for pronouns such as "I" and proper nouns such as "London". They are not used for "open source" which is short for "open source-code". In my humble opinion there is no dash needed in "open source" because "open" is a plain adjective and not an adverb, and source attaches to code and not to open